# Array of object arrays filtering does not retain the changes outside forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach

Use case: wrapping n object arrays in an array to loop over all arrays in one go and filter the objects on a property.

Known solutions I want to avoid:

```
[arr1,arr2,arr3] = [arr1,arr2,arr3].map(...)
```

---

```
["arr1","arr2","arr3"].forEach(arrName => window[arrName] = .....)
```

---

In the code below, why are the arrays not changed outside the forEach - some "pass by reference" issue? How to solve this?

Expected result:

```
[{"B":"b","remove":false},{"C":"c"}]
[{"A":"a","remove":false},{"C":"c","remove":false}]
[{"B":"b","remove":false}]
```

Actual result

```
[{"A":"a","remove":true},{"B":"b","remove":false},{"C":"c"}]
[{"A":"a","remove":false},{"B":"b","remove":true},{"C":"c","remove":false}]
[{"A":"a","remove":true},{"B":"b","remove":false},{"C":"c","remove":true}]
```

How to retain the changes outside the forEach?

```js
let arr1 = [
{"A":"a", "remove":true},
{"B":"b", "remove":false},
{"C":"c"}
];
let arr2 = [
{"A":"a", "remove": false},
{"B":"b", "remove": true},
{"C":"c", "remove": false}
];
let arr3 = [
{"A":"a", "remove": true},
{"B":"b", "remove": false},
{"C":"c", "remove": true}
];


[arr1, arr2, arr3]
  .forEach(arr =>  {
    arr = [...arr.filter(({remove})=> !remove)]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // works
  });
console.log("---------------");
// check it worked    
[arr1, arr2, arr3].forEach(arr => console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an array using objects, the array elements themselves become references to the objects you used to instantiate the array:

```
let a1 = { a: 1 };
let a = [ a1 ];
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints true
```

However, if you reassign a value to an element of that array, then that reference changes. The array element gets a new reference and breaks the link to the object used to first create the array:

```
let a1 = { a: 1 };
let a = [ a1 ];
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints true
a[0] = { a: 1 };
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints false
```

The vice-versa is true, if you re-assign a value to the variable you used to instantiate the array, the array element is not affected:

```
let a1 = { a: 1 };
let a = [ a1 ];
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints true
a1 = { a: 1 };
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints false
```

But if you simply change the property of the array element, then the references are unchanged:

```
let a1 = { a: 1 };
let a = [ a1 ];
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints true
a1['b'] = 2;
console.log(a[0] == a1);  // Prints true
console.log(JSON.stringify(a[0]));  // Prints '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

In fact, this is the behaviour for any object: a re-assignment changes its reference:

```
let a1 = { a: 1 };
let a2 = a2;
console.log(a1 == a2);  // Prints true
a2 = { a: 1 };
console.log(a1 == a1);  // Prints false
```

What you were doing in your `forEach()` was re-assigning new value. The [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a copy of the array it filtered, so it is not the same object as the original.

You can modify the callback to your `forEach()` to modify the same object. One way I could think of is by using a for-loop from the end of each array and remove items from the array using `splice()`:

```js
let arr1 = [
  {"A":"a", "remove":true},
  {"B":"b", "remove":false},
  {"C":"c"}
];
let arr2 = [
  {"A":"a", "remove": false},
  {"B":"b", "remove": true},
  {"C":"c", "remove": false}
];
let arr3 = [
  {"A":"a", "remove": true},
  {"B":"b", "remove": false},
  {"C":"c", "remove": true}
];


[arr1, arr2, arr3].forEach((arr, index) =>  {
    for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (arr[i].remove) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }        
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // works
  });
console.log("---------------");
// check it worked    
[arr1, arr2, arr3].forEach(arr => console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use map instead

```
const result = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
  .map(arr =>  {
    arr = [...arr.filter(({remove})=> !remove)]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // works
    return arr;
  });
```

if you want to reassign the values

```
 [arr1, arr2, arr3] = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
  .map(arr =>  {
    arr = [...arr.filter(({remove})=> !remove)]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // works
    return arr;
  });
```

Upd for the general array of arrays:

```
let t = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

  t.forEach((arr, key) =>  {
    t[key] = [...arr.filter(({remove})=> !remove)]
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // works
  });
```

Or if you want a general unsafe solution:

```
 let t = ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'];
    
  t.forEach((arrName) =>  {
     window[arrName] = [...window[arrName].filter(({remove})=> !remove)]
     console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // works
  });
```

Comment: The first one does not work - there is no reason at all to use map instead of a forEach if you do not use the result. In this case your first map is identical in result as my forEach. The SECOND DOES work, thank you.  Imagine however 20 arrays - we will have to write them out twice. Then there is nothing much gained.  I also want to know why the forEach does not work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not a problem, added the usecase for foreach=)

Comment: Please TEST your answers. The console.log in  `Upd for the general array of arrays` shows the expected values but they do not survive outside the forEach - it is the same as I already have but with t[key] instead of arr. I did not want to do the last one for obvious reasons. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

forEach does not change nothing on the arrays, just iterates on them, I'll recomend to use a .map to assign the returned result to a variable

[.map() doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: As the [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74161334/20303583) shows, a map is only working if you reassign the result of the map. In my forEach I have `arr = changedArr` and I expected that to work. It is not the loop that is the issue here, it's the reassignment to the original array that is the problem

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), *`forEach()` does not mutate the array on which it is called. However, [the] `callbackFn` [you pass to `forEach()`] may do so*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a "mainstream" answer, but if you really *want* to *change the original arrays* you could do the following:

```js
let arr1 = [
{"A":"a", "remove":true},
{"B":"b", "remove":false},
{"C":"c"}
];
const arr2 = [
{"A":"a", "remove": false},
{"B":"b", "remove": true},
{"C":"c", "remove": false}
];
let arr3 = [
{"A":"a", "remove": true},
{"B":"b", "remove": false},
{"C":"c", "remove": true}
];

[arr1, arr2, arr3].forEach(arr=>{
    let i=0;
    arr.forEach((c,_,a)=> c.remove||(a[i++]=c));
    arr.length = i;
  });
// check it worked    
[arr1, arr2, arr3].forEach(arr => console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)));
```

In this approach I replaced the `.filter()` by a `.forEach()` loop that reassigns individual elements of the processed array. And, as you can see, it also works on `const arr2` (I changed it into a `const` for demonstration purposes), whereas a reassignment via a `.map()` approach would not.

Comment: That is so weird. Why the need for the separate 'i' ?

Comment: In order to change elements of an array you must address them using the index method. In the inner `.forEach()` the `a` refers to the `arr` of the outer `forEach()` and `i` is a counter for "valid" elements (those without `.remove==true`).

Comment: It is not obvious how this runs. I’d have to step through to understand- especially where you shorten the array

Comment: I guess you got it now ;-) - well done!